# didSelectRowAtIndexPath with wrong NSIndexPath

Tags: tableview, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView which I have assigned sections. When using didSelectRowAtIndex with indexPath.actually, the NSIndexPath paramter is not correct.
eg 
in **section 1 row 0**, then the indexPath is **[0,1]** ;
**section 2 row 0 **,it get **[0, 2]**.while **section 0 row 1** is correct with  **[0, 1]** .*It seems section  0 is all correct.*

I am so frustrating and don't know why?
Can anyone tell me how to fix this or give me some advice?

the following is the code :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)sender 
{
return _store.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)sender numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if ([_store checkIfHasAdditionalContentInSection:section]) {
             return ([_store additionalContentInSection:section].count + 1);
        }
        return 1;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CallLogCell";
    CallLogCell *cell = [sender dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CallLogCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    CallLog *cLog = [_store itemAtIndex:indexPath];
    cell.callTimes = [_store callTimesAtIndex:indexPath];
    cell.callLog = cLog;
    cell.index = indexPath.section;
    [cell update];

    return cell;
}




- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)sender heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell=[self tableView:sender cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell.frame.size.height;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DLog(@"indexPath %@", [indexPath description]);
**//I always get incorrect answer at here**

DLog(@"indexPath section %d row %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row); 

[sender deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

fortunately I found the answer, others use strange code in the subclass UITableViewCell
here is the code:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    UITableView * tableView = (UITableView*)self.superview;
    if ([tableView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
        [tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
    }
}
```

when I delete it,it works well